# should i use Entity as a parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF 4 and have the following code.

```
    public static Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, Country> CountryDict { get; set; }
    public static Dictionary<int, State> StateDict { get; set; }
```

I ran memory profile and found that after filling these dictionaries, my ObjectContext doesnt get disposed because Country and State objects are still in the memory.

Am i using this incorrectly? Should i create a separate model class for Country and State and use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you populate these collections, you can `Detach` these objects from their context, so the ObjectContext doesn't try to track them anymore.

Also, it's usually best to create the ObjectContext in a `using` statement, to ensure that it gets disposed in a timely manner.

Comment: objectcontext is inside using statement.

Comment: I tried myObjectContext.Detach(myObjectContext.Coutries); but still i can see it in the memory. Isnt this the right way to detach the entity?

Comment: No, each object that you're keeping a reference to must be detached individually. `foreach(var country in CountryDict.Values) { myObjectContext.Detach(country);}`

Comment: thanks for the help. I see my ObjectContext being disposed properly. But i still see Country and State entities in the momory and the root object reference is pointing to the methods where i detached the objects.

Comment: As long as `CountryDict` and `StateDict` have values in them, you will still need to have those `Country` and `State` entities in memory, right? If you don't want them to exist, you could transfer the relevant data into a new DTO class to store in the dictionaries, but it's unclear how much that would buy you, since you're obviously trying to hold on to the data that's inside those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Disable object state tracking...